# Redirecting main site, except subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-alias

I did a number of search unsuccessfully before deciding to post this.

I have a main site, say `https://mainsite.com` and a subdomain, say, `https://subdomain.mainsite.com` .

Challenge is, I want to redirect only the main site to `https://mainsite.com/mysite` and not the subdomain.

I tried this:

```
RedirectMatch ^https://mainsite\.com https://mainsite.com/mysite
```

This wouldn't do anything if I type `https://mainsite.com`

Originally, I had this in-place and it worked fine for the main site:

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ /mysite
RedirectMatch /mysite/ /mysite
```

but when I had the subdomain, it added the `/mysite` to the subdomain as well, which isnt what I want.

I would like to achieve this with `Redirectmatch`

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on

#if http host not sub.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !sub\.domain\.com
redirect / to /mysite
RewriteRule ^/?$  /mysite [L,R]
```

On apache 2.4 you can enclose your `RedirectMatch` with `if` condition to check the host header, something  like the following should work on Apache 2.4 or more

```
 <If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'example.com'">
RedirectMatch ^/$ /mysite/
</If>
```

This will redirect `/` to `http://example.com/mysite` if the host is `example.com` .

Comment: This causes conflicts with other rewritecond. I would like to write this with redirectmatch. Thanks for your help.

Comment: hmm...getting internal server error for the one with if condition.

Comment: My mistake, missed the ">" in the closing If. Problem solved.  Thank You Starkeen!